# Client/Server program using Micro IP TCP/IP stack

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip

As a heads up, this question requires knowledge about the client/server program in the C language. I have already successfully written and executed a client/server program that basically does an exchange of variables from the client and the server through a socket connection.

My question is however, does anyone have a client/server code example using the Micro IP library? I.e, using functions such as `uip_listen()` or `uip_send()` instead of `listen()` and `write()` functions respectively.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I remember well, some examples are enclosed in uIP distribution.

Comment: @Marian Do you happen to have a link to the distribution? I've searched for some examples but haven't found anything.

Comment: After a 1 minute goole search: https://github.com/adamdunkels/uip/archive/uip-1-0.tar.gz